# Abnormal startup filter [jfinal],Tomcat failed to start DBConfigPlugin, database configuration file not found

Tags: java, tomcat

One or more filters in org. apache. catalina. core. StandardContext. startInternal failed to start. The complete detailed information will be found in the corresponding container log file,
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Abnormal startup filter jfinal
com.swan.platform.common.PlatformException: Failed to start DBConfigPlugin, database configuration file not found!(启动DBConfigPlugin失败，没有找到数据库配置文件！)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdRua.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbmB7.png)
The project can be run locally on IDEA and tomcat8.5, but deploying the project to tomcat8.5 on a remote server will result in an error